# Significance of Signed Zero

Tags: c++, math, ieee-754, zero, signed

Following C++ code outputs negative zero instead of positive.

```
double a = 0, b = -1;
double c = a / b ;
std::cout << c << std::endl;
```

As both zeros (+0 and -0) will compare equal, have the same mathematical value, then why it is required to support signed zero?

What is the significance of this difference?

Comment: The main implication is that a non-zero number divided by zero may result in plus or minus infinity depending on whether it is "plus zero" or "minus zero". Also is kind of a "natural consequence" of how floating point numbers are represented in IEEE-754.

Comment: Have you tried searching for it? Does e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero help you?

Comment: double a = 0, b = -1;
double c = a / b ;
std::cout << (c==0) << std::endl; this outputs 1, so I guess its just for noting that it was a result of negative value operations

Comment: Pretty sure that fits, if it doesn't, please edit to explain how exactly your question is different.

Comment: The same question has also been asked on another SE site and received a good answer: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/280648/why-is-negative-zero-important